# How to refer to the output of fully connected layer in tensorflow while restoring model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

If i am connecting a fully-connected layer like below and the output of this is the logits that i want to refer to while restoring the models but, there is no `name` argument available in  `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected`. Below is what i want to do but it throws error

```
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outl[str(i)], self.classes, activation_fn = None, 
                                                           weights_initializer = self.initializer,
                                                          name = 'mlogits')

fully_connected() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

What is the tensor name of the output of this fully connected layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can just access to the complete name of the output tensor using the `.name` property:

```
print(logits.name)
```

This is the **complete** name of your output tensor